# Accessing Windows Encrypted partition in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, encryption

I have a windows partition which has been encrypted by Credant Mobile Guardian. 
The windows AD credentials are used to encrypt the files. And they are encrypted using an AES 256 encryption algo. (Rijandel 256).

Is there any way I can open these files in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

No, in addition to the authentication required to unlock the encryption keys, the solution uses a filter driver in Windows to read/write encrypted data.  To my knowledge there is no driver for Linux.

Comment: I can get the encryption keys from the application inside windows.
so given these, is there any way to read the files inside Linux?